# Como configurar un determinada ruta inicial en next js y que no comienze desde index

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nextjs

- Como configurar una determinada ruta de partida en un proyecto de next js y que no comienze por el index.js como siempre
- O sino tbn como hacer que desde el index.js se maneje una condicion y segun esta automaticamente cambie a una ruta determinar que quisiera
- Intente crear un state el cual segun su condicion saltar a una ruta determinada tan solo poniendo el componente `<Login />` de dicha ruta el cual esta en `page/auth/login` el cual si me dirige al componente, pero en la ruta del navegador no aparece su ruta `http://localhost:3000/auth/login` sino solo de la ruta inicial `http://localhost:3000/` y yo quisiera que cambie tbn la ruta y que no solo se muestre el componente

```js
const MainApp: NextPage = () => {

  const { isLoggedIn, user } = useContext(AuthContext)

  if(!isLoggedIn){
    return <Login />
  }

  return (
    <MainLayout title='Login' pageDescription='Login Page'>
        <FullScreenLoading />
    </MainLayout>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola lo que yo intentaría es desde el App

//importa aquí tus componentes    const { isLoggedIn, user }  = useContext(AuthContext)

```
function App () {
     return (
        <div>
          {isLoggedIn ? (
            <Login/>
          ):
           <MainLayout title='Login' pageDescription='Login Page'>
        <FullScreenLoading />
    </MainLayout>
         }
        </div>  
     )

   }
```

Espero que te sirva, espero tu respuesta

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.